# Database design for junior football two divisions east/west with four teams in each division

Tags: database

Current design:

- **Gamestable**: Gameid, dmy, starttime, dayplayed, weeknumber, Hometeamdivisionid, Hometeamid, Awayteamdivisionid, Awayteamid, Hometeampointsscored, Awayteampointsscored, win-loss
- **Hometeamdivisiontable**: Hometeamdivisionid
- **Hometeamtable**: Hometeamid
- **Awayteamdivisiontable**: Awayteamdivisionid
- **Awayteamtable**: Awayteamid

Do I need more tables, or just different tables?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  You really need to put a little more of your question into the main body of the question rather than in the title.  You should probably also explain a bit more of your thinking behind the design.

Comment: sorry, I did not notice it earlier on and won't happen again.

Answer (score 1):

#### Initial observations

You do not need separate tables for 'home team' and 'away team'.  Think about it: you have teams; these are organized into divisions; they play games.  In any given game, one team is the home team and one team is the away team, but for different games, a given team can be the home team or the away team.  A given team belongs to one division at a time.  So you need a design somewhat like this:

- **Division**: Division ID, Name (...)
- **Team**: Team ID, Division ID, Name (...)
- **Game**: Game ID, Date Played, Start Time, Home Team ID, Away Team ID, Home Team Score, Away Team Score (...)

Clearly, there are constraints on the values in the Game table, such as 'Home Team ID' is not equal to the 'Away Team ID'.  There might be more complex constraints too: the two teams must be in the same division (if there is no inter-divisional play).  You have two foreign key constraints from Game to Team.

From these, everything else can be calculated.  You might need a 'calendar' table to define 'week number'; it is probably the easiest way to determine which week of a season a given game was played in:

- **Calendar**: Date, Season ID, Week Number (...)

If you have to deal with 'Team A' was in west division in Spring 2012 but in east division for Autumn 2012, etc, then you need more complexity, but while you only have to record one season at a time, so a team is always in the same division, then you're pretty much good to go.

---

#### Now more information is available

The overall goal is to record the games played in a league over a number of seasons.  The teams making up the league are stable, and there are just two divisions, but teams can move between divisions in different seasons (but not during a season).

The first necessary change is to the Team table; the `Division ID` is now a property of the team for a particular season, not a permanent attribute.  The calendrical issues are more important too.

- **Season**: Season ID (PK), Name, Start Date, End Date (...)
- **Division**: Division ID (PK), Name (...)
- **Team**: Team ID (PK), Name (...)  *(no Division ID here)*
- **SeasonDivisionTeam**: Season ID, Division ID, Team ID (PK is all three attributes)
- **Game**: Game ID (PK), Date Played, Start Time, Home Team ID, Away Team ID, Home Team Score, Away Team Score, Venue ID, (...)
- **Calendar**: Date (PK), Season ID, Week Number (...)

The name SeasonDivisionTeam is not good; I'm drawing a blank on a better name, though.  It basically defines which teams were in each division for each season.  It is an 'all key' table, with three separate foreign keys.  There are constraints between the season table (with its start and end dates) and the calendar table.  The dates designated for a specific season in the calendar table must not fall outside the range of dates designated for the same season in the season table.  Alternatively, you could drop the season dates from the season table and let the calendar table define the valid ranges of dates.

You'd probably end up with some statistical tables that summarize the data in the main operational tables.  For example, calculating the standings in a division for a particular date is doable, but modestly expensive computationally.  You might have a summary table for recording the 'end of season' standings.  You could have entries in it for the end of each week if you wanted to.

I'm not sure what's best to do with the playoffs.  The game table is able to record the raw data.  You might want to add a Venue column to record where the game was played.  Since this is a junior division, I can imagine that you have a knockout tournament on one or two days at the end of the season — or maybe a tiered tournament with a round-robin phase and then a knockout phase.  In this case, you might have a cluster of games played in a short time.  Or you might have the games spaced out more regularly.  The structure of the Games table can record any of these variations.  However, you might find it sensible to devise a table for defining the structure of the playoffs.  What works best may depend on how stable the playoff organization has been.  For that, more information is needed.  However, for the simple matter of recording games, the outlined Games table has no problem.  The issue is how humans attach meaning to the playoff games.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I will be entering data from 1996 to present 2012 seaeson. teams have changed division say west in 1996 moved to east for 1997 season then to west in 2001. for playoffs would I make a postseason table with different rounds of the playoffs?

Comment: Were all the teams that played in 2012 league also in the 1996 league, or have some teams gone and new ones arrived? You'll end up needing more tables.  For example, the calendar table probably becomes more important, or you might perhaps have a set of related calendar tables.  You'll still have the Team table, but the Division ID information needs to go into a separate table that includes the Season ID, Division ID and Team ID (assuming teams don't change division during a season).  You'll need to think through the rules a bit, but the Game table I proposed does not need to change, I think.

Comment: Recording playoffs; you probably could use the same Game table, but you'd also want more information somewhere about the fact that they're playoff games, so I'd be tempted to introduce new tables.  However, [Occam's Razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) (_entia non sunt multiplicanda praeter necessitatum_ or 'do not multiply entities without necessity') applies very much to database design (and OO design).

Comment: same team names that never changed just one less team in the league and a team swiches division.  Also Jonathan, the East Division Teams do play West Division Teams I call this Inter Division play and trying to stay normalized

Comment: Most of the information in your comments should be added to the question, really.  (You can edit your own questions; you can also post comments to answers to your own questions, even as a newcomer, even though you'd not be able to post comments to questions or answers where you didn't ask the question.)  There's nothing in the design that prevents inter-divisional play; indeed, outlawing it would be hard to do (not impossible, but modestly hard).